# Storing raw data for complex calculations

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, in-memory-database

We have a web application for reporting where all the data resides in a relational database. For most of the reports, we can do all the calculations with the built-in aggregator functions provided by the engine or by pre-calculating and caching the results. The performance of generating those reports to the users are very fast.

There are only two cases where we need to run a very complex algorithm based on trial and error that cannot be accomplished via SQL nor anything can be pre-cached in the database. There are also too many input variations that it is impossible to cache the results. The algorithm also requires all the data at the same time and therefore it is not possible to divide and do in parallel or to fetch in chunks.

So we are currently preparing those reports by getting the raw data from the database and calculating the logic in C#. This is however slow as we need to fetch all that data that can reach up to 8GB at the moment to the backend. Also, many heavy concurrent requests might cause a limitation in the available memory at the VMs.

We are already fetching the minimum amount of rows and columns (2 numeric fields and 1 date field) to do the algorithm and based on that we cannot improve the performance by reducing the size of transferred data. So we tried to speed it as PoC by doing the following:

- In-memory databases for caching raw data (Redis, Memcached): While reading from the database was very fast, we faced a large problem in deserialization that can take up to 9 seconds for the data we have. We tried multiple deserialization algorithms but none of them were fast enough for large amount of data.
- Storing raw data in memory (local cache): This provided obviously the best performance possible by finalizing the calculations in less than a second. However, this is not ideal as it is not scalable and might even cause problems with garbage collection according to many sources online.

My question is whether there is a recommendation from an architectural point of view where we can speed up the reports to something close to local cache speed without the limitations caused by it. We use .NET Core and SQL server if that helps.

Comment: In most cases you may consider doing some calculations in the insert  phase. Maybe create a dedicated table that will allow you to hold some of these calculations. It is very hard to advise on such a vague problem description(loading the entire DB to do some calculations seems like something you would want to avoid at all cost)

Comment: That is what we do for the other reports that we have but for these 2 particular reports, it is impossible to cache any part unfortunately. I can't go much in the details of the algorithm as it is proprietary but the concept is a root-finding algorithm to estimate the best answer. Such an algorithm would require looping on data points and doing financial calculations not available in SQL to find the answer. The client can choose the data points involved and therefore it is impossible to also cache the results as too many variations

Comment: Why do you think caching the data locally isn't scalable?

Comment: My two concerns are:
- Size of data: 8GB is still fine but the more clients we get, the more challenging it will be to store all that data at the same time.
- Load balancing where we need to manually update all local cache for each instance (Doable but we need to maintain it manually)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a technique we've employed in the time series analytics component of our database system, pipelining, would be helpful. You can read about the technique here (anonymously, no registration required): [Pipelining Vector-Based Statistical Functions for In-Memory Analytics](https://www.mcobject.com/download/pipelining-vector-based-statistical-functions-for-in-memory-analytics/)

I understand you're using SQL Server; this isn't a plug for our database system. I read your question and thought the technique might be helpful in that it might eliminate the need to cache all the data, and preserves the ability to use SQL (a pipeline is built by nesting functions in a SQL statement). However, if the data is not time series, the technique might also not be applicable.